# MVC Model Error on TryUpdateModel()

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an error (see below). At first glance it seems obvious to me, however. I've checked everything: the MODEL is ok; metadata class set ok and i've checked my controller and at the time 'TryUpdateMOdel' is called all is well and the object is as i expect it to be. I'm thinking this will be something silly but been stuck all day, anyone recommend anything?

The associated metadata type for type '*Lms.Model.PaymentFrequency*' contains the following unknown properties or fields: SiteAgreementId, PaymentTypeId, PaymentCategoryId, ObligationStartDate, TerminationDate, Comments. Please make sure that the names of these members match the names of the properties on the main type.

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.InvalidOperationException: The associated metadata type for type 'Lms.Model.PaymentFrequency' contains the following unknown properties or fields: SiteAgreementId, PaymentTypeId, PaymentCategoryId, ObligationStartDate, TerminationDate, Comments. Please make sure that the names of these members match the names of the properties on the main type.

**Source Error:**

```
Line 120:            PaymentFrequency paymentFrequency = this._siteRepository.GetPayment(Convert.ToInt16(collection["PaymentId"])).PaymentFrequency;
Line 121:
Line 122:            TryUpdateModel(paymentFrequency);
Line 123:
Line 124:            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the metadata class you have attached to your PaymentFrequency model may have properties the model itself doesn't.

Comment: That helped me a lot .. thanks.
I had the same error and it was due to misspelling error in the meta data class.